# How I can get all the values of select tag if 'id' of select tag is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, select, dropdown, selector

**Problem:** I have dropdown menus (around 10 on one page and each have different id ). I am trying to automate those control fields, where I need to set the value of dropdown menu and I am trying to implement a generic solution for all dropdown menu.

**For Example:** For given dropdown menu, I want to set its value to Korean (ECU-KR).

**My Approach:**
To automate this dropdown, I am trying to get all the values of select tag and iterating each to compare with the require value (that I want to set in dropdown menu(Korean (ECU-KR))). But I stuck here.....

**Need Help In:**

1. How to get 'id' of select tag ?
2. If I get id, then How I can get all the values of a particular select tag ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the value you want to set – and with the assumption that only one `<option>` element exists with that value – I’d suggest not worrying about the `<select>` element and instead focus on the `<option>`:

```
// select the <option> element by its value attribute:
let option = document.querySelector('option[value="ECU-KR"]'),
    // if you still have need of the <select> element:
    select = option.closest('select');
// set the selected property of the <option>:
option.selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can fetch the element by getElementById. the selected value can be retrieved by the value of the dropdown. the options property contains array which hold all of the options found on the dropdown so you can iterate over them and get their values.

```js
function onChange(event) {
  const id = event.id;
  console.log(id);
  var select = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log("selected = " + select.value);
  var options= new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
   options[i] = select.options[i].value;
  }
  console.log("options = " + options)
}
```

```html
<select id="57" onchange="onChange(this)">
  <option value="UTF-8">UTF-8</option>
  <option value="ISO-859">ISO-859</option>
  <option value="euc-kr">euc-kr</option>
</select>
```

Comment: id is not fixed, so can't implement this logic with id =57

Comment: I changed the code so it's not fixed. take a look now @RaviSharma

Answer (score 1):

## Getting the id of a selector

Assuming that you already have a variable called `selector`, its `id` can be determined by `selector.id`.

## Getting the ids of all selects

```
for (let select of document.querySelectorAll('select')) {
    //do something with select.id
}
```

## Getting selects by id pattern

Since your `id` contains colon, I will assume that the `select` tags you are interested about all have colon in their `id`. In this case:

```
for (let select of document.querySelectorAll('select[id*=":"]')) {
    //Do something with select.id
}
```

The *= is the contains selector.

## Getting the values of selects having some id pattern

```
let values = {};
for (let select of document.querySelectorAll('select[id*=":"]')) {
    values[select.id] = [];
    for (let option of select.querySelectorAll('option')) {
        values.push(option.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

````
let x = document.getElementById("57:").selectedIndex;
let values = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;```
````

This should do that for you.

Comment: id is not fixed, its different for all dropdown menu and want to implement a generic solution